# batch file - counting number of files in folder and storing in a variable

Tags: batch-file

I am very new to this. Please help me

I was trying to write a batch file program to count number of files in a folder and assign that to a variable and display it to verify that it has been stored
please help me with the syntax,

thank you in advance
-VK

Answer (score 63):

I'm going to assume you do not want to count hidden or system files.

There are many ways to do this. All of the methods that I will show involve some form of the FOR command. There are many variations of the FOR command that look almost the same, but they behave very differently. It can be confusing for a beginner.

You can get help by typing `HELP FOR` or `FOR /?` from the command line. But that help is a bit cryptic if you are not used to reading it.

1) The DIR command lists the number of files in the directory. You can pipe the results of DIR to FIND to get the relevant line and then use FOR /F to parse the desired value from the line. The problem with this technique is the string you search for has to change depending on the language used by the operating system.

```
@echo off
for /f %%A in ('dir ^| find "File(s)"') do set cnt=%%A
echo File count = %cnt%
```

2) You can use `DIR /B /A-D-H-S` to list the non-hidden/non-system files without other info, pipe the result to FIND to count the number of files, and use FOR /F to read the result.

```
@echo off
for /f %%A in ('dir /a-d-s-h /b ^| find /v /c ""') do set cnt=%%A
echo File count = %cnt%
```

3) You can use a simple FOR to enumerate all the files and SET /A to increment a counter for each file found.

```
@echo off
set cnt=0
for %%A in (*) do set /a cnt+=1
echo File count = %cnt%
```

Comment: How do you specify the dir in which you want to count in the first method??

Comment: @LoukMo - The answer assumes current directory. To specify a different folder, simply put the path after the DIR command.

Answer (score 13):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
set count=0
for %%x in (*.txt) do set /a count+=1
echo %count%
endlocal
pause
```

This is the best.... your variable is:   `%count%`

NOTE: you can change (`*.txt`) to any other file extension to count other files.....

Comment: This works well, but note that files with the `System` or `Hidden` attribute (eg. `attrib +s MyFile.txt`) are counted with this script but are not listed with `dir`!

Comment: This is conceptually identical to the 3rd option in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11005300/1012053) from 3 years earlier. Why post an identical answer?

Comment: @dbenham _Why post an identical answer?_ Assumedly seeking for reputation. I tend to flag such answers and give a reference to the original answer.

Answer (score 8):

The [mugume david answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15485610/1012053) fails on an empty folder; Count is 1 instead of a 0 when looking for a pattern rather than all files. For example *.xml

This works for me:

`attrib.exe /s ./*.xml | find /v "File not found - " | find /c /v ""`

Answer (score 8):

This might be a bit faster:

```
dir /A:-D /B *.* 2>nul | find /c /v ""
```

```
`/A:-D` - filters out only non directory items (files)
`/B`    - prints only file names (no need a full path request)
`*.*`   - can filters out specific file names (currently - all)
`2>nul` - suppresses all error lines output to does not count them
```

To build `for` statement you should know some details at first.

```
for /F %%i in ('dir /A:-D /B *.* 2^>nul ^| find /c /v ""') do set "COUNT=%%i"
```

The example above would work, but if you want to copy paste it into another for-expression - might not.

The `for /F ...` expression by default has `;` character as EOL character and space+tabulation characters as line separators.

If you use a file path as input in for-expression, then you can override these characters:

```
for /F "eol= delims=" %%i in (";My file path") do echo.Value: %%i
```

Where the end of `eol=` might not visible here. It is just a file path invalid not printable character, in this case - code `04`. In most consoles and editors (except stackoverflow itself) you can type it as:

- press `ALT`
- type `04` from numeric keypad
- release `ALT`

Another issue avoid here is always reset variable you want to use before the for-expression in case if for-expression is not executed:

```
set FILE=undefined
for /F %%i in (";My file path") do set "FILE=%%i"
echo.FILE=%FILE%
```

Comment: And how to set var to the found number of files in cmd batch file?

Answer (score 7):

The fastest code for counting files with ANY attributes in folder `%FOLDER%` and its subfolders is the following. The code is for script in a command script (batch) file.

```
@for /f %%a in ('2^>nul dir "%FOLDER%" /a-d/b/-o/-p/s^|find /v /c ""') do set n=%%a
@echo Total files: %n%.
```

Answer (score 3):

Change into the directory and;

```
attrib.exe /s ./*.* |find /c /v ""
```

#### EDIT

I presumed that would be simple to discover. use

```cs
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "batchfile.bat";
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

I run this and the variable `output` was holding this

```
D:\VSS\USSD V3.0\WTU.USSD\USSDConsole\bin\Debug>attrib.exe /s ./*.*   | find /c /v "" 13
```

where 13 is the file count. It should solve the issue

Comment: The OP did not ask to count files in sub-folders, so I don't see the reason for `/s` option. The OP did ask for the result to be stored in a variable, and your code does not do that.

Answer (score 1):

`for /F "tokens=1" %a in ('dir ^| findstr "File(s)"') do echo %a`

Result:

```
C:\MyDir> for /F "tokens=1" %a in ('dir ^| findstr "File(s)"') do @set FILE_COUNT=%a

C:\MyDir> echo %FILE_COUNT%
4   // <== There's your answer
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('attrib.exe ./*.* ^| find /v "File not found - " ^| find /c /v ""') DO SET myVar=%%i
ECHO %myVar%
```

This is based on the (much) earlier post that points out that the count would be wrong for an empty directory if you use DIR rather than attrib.exe.

For anyone else who got stuck on the syntax for putting the command in a FOR loop, enclose the command in single quotes (assuming it doesn't contain them) and escape pipes with ^.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a temporary file to do this in the past, like this below.

```
DIR /B *.DAT | FIND.EXE /C /V "" > COUNT.TXT

FOR /F "tokens=1" %%f IN (COUNT.TXT) DO (
IF NOT %%f==6 SET _MSG=File count is %%f, and 6 were expected. & DEL COUNT.TXT & ECHO #### ERROR - FILE COUNT WAS %%f AND 6 WERE EXPECTED. #### >> %_LOGFILE% & GOTO SENDMAIL
)
```

Answer (score 1):

With a `for` loop:

```
FOR /F %i IN ('dir /b /a-d "%cd%" ^| find /v /c "?"') DO set /a count=%i
echo %count%
```

Without/avoiding `for` loop:

```
(dir /b /a-d ^| find /v /c "?") | (set /p myVar=& cmd /c exit /b %myVar%)
set count=%errorlevel%
echo %count%
```

Tested in Win 10 cmd

Comment: The first one is already shown, but the second one is interesting! But could be simplified to `dir /b /a-d | find /v /c "" | (set /p cnt= & cmd /c exit /b %cnt%)`. Btw to get it working in a batch file, the last part has to be changed to `cmd /c exit /b %%cnt%%`

Comment: Hehe I knew you'd like it; I haven't seen anyone do it before :)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

- Requires **[enabling Windows Subsystems For Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install)**
- Ensure `directoryToCount` is set to the respective directory

```
SET directoryToCount=C:\Users\
dir %directoryToCount% > contentsOfDir.txt
echo cat contentsOfDir.txt ^| grep File > countFiles.sh
sh countFiles.sh
del countFiles.sh
del contentsOfDir.txt
```

### Explanation

- In both `bash` and `batch` environments, the output of a command can be redirected to a file using the `>` operator.

  - For example, `echo hello world > myFile.txt` will produce a file named `myFile.txt` with `hello world` as its text.
- In a `bash` environment, one can `cat` the contents of a File and `grep` a particular line from the file containing a specified pattern.

  - For example, `cat myFile.txt | grep hello` will return lines containing `hello`
- If Windows Subsystems for Linux is enabled, then one can execute `sh` from a Command Prompt to access a linux-like environment.
- Therefore, we can solve this by doing the following

  1. Use `dir` to acquire a list of files in the directory, as well as the number of files
  2. Redirect the output of `dir` to a file (perhaps named `contentsOfDir.txt`).
  3. Create a `.sh` file to `grep` for `File` from `contentsOfDir.txt`
  4. Call the `.sh` file from command prompt to invoke the `grep`
  5. Delete the `.sh` file
  6. Delete `contentsOfDir.txt`