# Counting the number of files according to filename pattern using cmd

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder in which there are a bunch of various kinds of text files. The filenames are constructed so that there's a main body and a date in the filename, for example:

```
AAA_20150630.txt 
AAA_20150629.txt
BBB_20150630.txt
CCC_20150630.txt
CCC_20150701.txt
```

Now I want to count how many files there are for each type of file, so that in this case the desired result would be:

```
AAA 2
BBB 1
CCC 2
```

I also have another text file, `filelist.txt`, that lists all possible types, ie.

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

I'm trying to build a CMD script that would loop through the rows of `filelist.txt` and count the occurrances of each type of file in the folder.

So far, I've been following the advice in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926768/using-batch-to-count-the-number-of-specific-files-in-folder) question, succesfully building a script for counting how many times a single type of file appears (%source_dir% is my folder that has been set earlier on):

```
set count=0
for /f %%k in ('dir /b /a-d %source_dir%\AAA_* ^| find /c /v ""') do set count=%%k 
echo number of AAA files = %count%
```

However, I ran into a problem when trying to build another for-loop around this one in order to go through all the types of file listed in filelist:

```
for /f %%i in (%filelist%) do (
    set count=0
    for /f %%j in ('dir /b /a-d %source_dir%\%%i_* ^| find /c /v ""') do set count=%%j
    echo number of %%i files = %count%
)
```

This code does not work: it loops through all the rows, but it only counts the actual number for the first item in %filelist%, and then returns that result for all consecutive ones.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need delayed expansion with `!` to use variables inside loops and ifs:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%i in (%filelist%) do (
    set count=0
    for /f %%j in ('dir /b /a-d !source_dir!\%%i_* ^| find /c /v ""') do set count=%%j
    echo number of %%i files = !count!
)
pause
```

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you! I actually already had delayed expansion set earlier, but hadn't figured out the exclamation marks. Rookie mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit simpler alternative.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "sourcedir=path\to\some\folder"

for /f %%I in (filelist.txt) do (
    for %%A in (%sourcedir%\%%I*) do set /a count[%%I] += 1
)

set count
```

It should also be a bit more efficient.

Comment: Nice, thank you. The extra efficiency is achieved by not having to execute that separate "find" command? I did notice my original script was a bit slow. However, as my filelist.txt is extremely unlikely to ever have more than ~30 entries, we're talking about mere seconds. If someone else does something similar with a bigger list, this is obviously a better way of doing it.

Comment: It's more efficient both because it doesn't have to execute `find` and because `for` is faster than `for /f`.