# Counting files using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I tried the following code in a .bat file to count the number of files in a directory:

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /A-D /B /S | find /C /V ""') do set FILECOUNT=%%a
echo %FILECOUNT%
pause
```

However, it doesn't work and doesn't even pause. It instead flashes something like ": was unexpected at this time".
If I just write

```
dir /A-D /B /S | find /C /V ""
pause
```

It works fine and displays the number of files but I want to save this number into a variable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004045/batch-file-counting-number-of-files-in-folder-and-storing-in-a-variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the pipe, so

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('dir /A-D /B /S ^| find /C /V ""') do set FILECOUNT=%%a
echo %FILECOUNT%
pause
```

Comment: @J.Doe if my answer solved your problem, you should click the check to the left of it so people searching on google for the same problem can find it.